# NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseRequest. Android Parse Exception

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin

I have create one sample app using `parse.com` jar. In this project Buid version `SDK` was 22(it was running fine). But after change it with 23 I am facing some issues in compiling app. I have tried to clean project, Invalidate caches. Rebuild project etc  but I faced same issue error is:`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseRequest
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:184)` I can't get find exact solution. I have checked libs folder have jar. I have also tried with latest `gradle` code but faced same error. After removing parse jar I can compile my project.  My dependencies are

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile project(':MaterialShowcaseView')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')

}
```

If I Change this dependencies with `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'` then error is different. Error is:`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParsePlugins$1
at com.parse.ParsePlugins.restClient(ParsePlugins.java:92)
at com.parse.Parse.initializeParseHttpClientsWithParseNetworkInterceptors(Parse.java:762)
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:365)
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:344)`
Please suggest me,  what is wrong with this dependency. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have to check if Export is checked for Your library: Right click on your project -> "Module settings" -> Dependencies  and then check if the Export is checked...

Comment: @ Opiatefuchs I have checked it dependency I can see that was linked http://screencast.com/t/fUynUfMqZ

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  is there any other setting I need to change? I have checked one other jar is working fine with this dependacy

Comment: first clean Your project, this is often a problem...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  more than 20 times done this process. even close studio rebuid, reindexing everything tried.

Comment: I read about to better clean gradle from commandline....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028009/android-studio-build-clean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is not because of parse class.In error you get that error because of [mulitdex](http://goo.gl/pAOFU4) not handled & Initilization of parse is on app start up thats why it will give class not found error.

add below lines to `build.gradle`  to handle multi dex

To resolve issue what i give in my build.gradle

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        // here heap size give 4g i got this thing from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    your dependencies which you are using.

}
```

Entire **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}
configurations {
//    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        /*
        releasebuild {
            keyAlias 'hellotest'
            keyPassword 'hellotest'
            storeFile file('path to keystore')
            storePassword 'hellotest'
        }
        */
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    /* if you got error regarding duplicate file of  META-INF/LICENSE.txt from jar file
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    */
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        incremental true
        // here heap size give 4g i got this thing from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.myapp.packagenme"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releasebuild
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releasebuild
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    your dependencies which you are using.

}
```

With the help of [android developer multidex guide MultiDexApplication class](http://goo.gl/ih0kp9)

To install `MultiDex.install` i refer [android developer link](http://goo.gl/eFs0ML)

```
public class MyAppClass extends MultiDexApplication{
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        MultiDex.install(newBase);
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }
}
```

***Suggestion***

**[Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://goo.gl/dWqBbi)**

Don't use entire google play service use only required library.From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
```

Let me know if anything.

Comment: @bhavin check the updated answer with suggestion. by using required play service library may solve your problem without adding multidex.

Comment: I haven't tried your full code but "Suggestion" work for me. Removed unused play-services individual work for me no need multi-dex Thanks for this great help.

Comment: @bhavinchauhan suggestion worked thn error is multi dex only so my code will also work.. :)