# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError retrofit2.Utils

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit to handle the Serverside Data from Mobile. After Implementing retrofit, I am Getting the below Exception.

What am I doing wrong?

> com.name.App_idea W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   retrofit2.Utils
>       at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:434)
>       at com.name.App_idea.utils.Idea.onCreate(Idea.java:103)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4541)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Retrofit Init**

```
mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(AppConstance.APP_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getOkHttpClient())
                    .build();
```

**Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.App_idea"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "9"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

**Application Class**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class Idea extends Application {
    public static Retrofit mRetrofit;
    public static IdeaService Iservice;


    public static LoginResponceModel loinResponce;
    public static SettingsModel settingModel;

    public static LocationModel location = new LocationModel();

    private static SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    private static String FILE_PATH;

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDataBase() {
        return dbase;
    }

    public static String getFilePath() {
        return FILE_PATH;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "App", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(AppConstance.DbConstans.tblLogin);
            Log.i("DB", "Created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteAllTables() {
        getDataBase().execSQL("DELETE FROM login");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(AppConstance.APP_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getOkHttpClient())
                    .build();
            Iservice = mRetrofit.create(IdeaService.class);
            MultiDex.install(this);
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            dbase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            AppDataService appDataService = new AppDataService();
            loinResponce = appDataService.getLoginDetails();
            settingModel = appDataService.getSettings();

            FILE_PATH = getAppFilePath();
            startService(new Intent(Idea.this, LocationTracker.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String combineFilePath(String path1, String path2) {
        File file1 = new File(path1);
        File file2 = new File(file1, path2);
        return file2.getPath();
    }

    public String getAppFilePath() {

        String dsPath;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            dsPath = combineFilePath(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                    "android/data/Idea/");
        else
            dsPath = this.getDir(
                    this.getPackageName(), 0).getAbsolutePath();

        new File(dsPath).mkdirs();
        return dsPath;
    }

    private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };
            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your baseurl properly in Utils class  and use the concatenated part in the interfce like I have added in my code.@Muthu Pandiyan

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: Please try to remove `.client(getOkHttpClient())` line

Comment: still same issue    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(AppConstance.APP_URL)
                    .build();

Comment: Ok, try creating a new project, with only contents as in your question, then run the app.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means that the class was present at compile time, but couldn't be found at runtime by the JVM. Do you observe this behaviour in an Application class that only contains retrofit-specific code? I'm thinking a duplicate class called DatabaseHelper could be defined in one of your dependencies.

Comment: Did you try multidex like i suggested in one of my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Gradle bulid configure issue i also got same issue Some times

In Gradle your using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Enire Google Playservice Lib can you change into which are the lib's using in your project

**Example**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
```

Refer This URl https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Answer (score 13):

This error will come because of [MultiDexApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html) .I have face this kind of issue with some other library not same library but some other library.It will error of the retrofit library because its initialization of app start up where dex(in which your  retrofit library code is converted to dex) file is not to set(install).

To resolve that you need to handle Multiple Dex file. with the help of application `build.gradle` & Application class

below changes which is required in `build.gradle` file

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        // here heap size give 4g i got this thing from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    your dependencies which you are using.

}
```

entire `build.gradle`

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        /*
        releasebuild {
            keyAlias 'hellotest'
            keyPassword 'hellotest'
            storeFile file('path to keystore')
            storePassword 'hellotest'
        }
        */
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    /* if you got error regarding duplicate file of  META-INF/LICENSE.txt from jar file
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    */
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        incremental true
        // here heap size give 4g i got this thing from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.myapp.packagenme"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releasebuild
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releasebuild
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    your dependencies which you are using.

}
```

If your app uses extends the Applicationclass, you can override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call `MultiDex.install(this)` to enable multidex. [To install multipledex file](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#testing) context using Applicaiton class which should extends `[MultiDexApplication][2]`

```
public class MyAppClass extends MultiDexApplication{
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        MultiDex.install(newBase);
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }
}
```

**Suggestion**

[**Selectively compiling APIs into your executable**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Don't use entire google play service use only required library.From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
```

With the reference of my answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34948154/1140237

Comment: @MuthuPandiyan have followed all the steps which are given in my answer ? as same issue i got and resolved by doing this..

Comment: @MuthuPandiyan you can also try suggestion which i gave selectively adding play service. well it reduces dex file size but to resolve actual dex issue follow answer with gradle file & Application class

Comment: i will try @user1140237

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this error below lollipop devices.

I was using multiDexEnabled true.

After adding this code to the class extending Application class my issue solved.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968486/4777524

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the following proguard rules?

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

Documentation: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 1):

You should make Utils class like this:

```
public class AppUtil{
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging=new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        if(isEnableLogging)
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        else
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                        return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .create();
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.URL_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

    }



}
```

Create an interface like this for the http methods:

```
public interface EndPointInterface{
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Constants.URL_LOGON)
    Call<Doctor> login(@Field(Constants.EMAIL) String email,
                       @Field(Constants.PASSWORD) String password);
}
```

In your activity where you are calling the webservices,please proceed like this:

```
 @OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
    public void onLoginButtonClick() {
        String emailString = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordString = edtPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (emailString.length() == 0) {
            emailWrapper.setError("Please enter E-Mail ID");
        } else if (!AppUtil.isEmailValid(emailString)) {
            emailWrapper.setError("Please enter valid E-Mail ID");
        } else if (passwordString.length() == 0) {
            passwordWrapper.setError("Please enter password");
        } else if (AppUtil.isNetworkConnectionAvailable(this, true)) {
            login(emailString,passwordString);
        }
    }

 private void login(String email, String pwd) {
        final MaterialDialog dialog = AppUtil.showIndeterminateProgressDialog(this,getString(R.string.please_wait));
        EndPointInterface apiService = AppUtil.getRetrofitInstance().create(EndPointInterface.class);
        Call<Doctor> call = apiService.login(email, pwd);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Doctor>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Doctor> call, Response<Doctor> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Doctor doctor = response.body();
                    if (doctor == null) {
                        AppUtil.showSimpleDialog(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.userid_pwd_mismatched),
                                getString(R.string.login_credential_mismatch));
                    } else {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mAppPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(Constants.SETTINGS_OBJ_DOCTOR, new Gson().toJson(doctor));
                        editor.putBoolean(Constants.SETTINGS_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
                        editor.commit();

                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PatientSummaryInfoActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    AppUtil.showSimpleDialog(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.server_error),
                            getString(R.string.could_not_connect_to_server));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Doctor> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                AppUtil.showSimpleDialog(LoginActivity.this,getString(R.string.server_error), t.getMessage());
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Please add your classes @Muthu Pandiyan so that we can see where is the actual error.

Comment: i added the App class @CrazyAndroid can please help on this issue

Comment: are you calling it in your activity @Muthu Pandiyan because your exception seems to be in onCreate Method.And where are you calling call.enque method?

Comment: If none of the solution is working out I request you to relax a bit ,then try to think deeply about the solution.Please run your app in debug mode you may get a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem by changing retrofit gradle version 2.7.0  to  2.5.0

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(AppConstance.APP_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getOkHttpClient())
                    .build();
```

REWRITE TO

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(AppConstance.APP_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(httpClient)
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

With these many library saddles up, it must have exceded the infamous 64k method limit, you need to enable your app for multidex. Here is how you do it. https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same lib version for base retrofit lib and the converters.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues like this, it's probably a dependency issue

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
```

already includes okhttp as seen here https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/d04f3a50e41ca01d22f370ac4f332f6ddf4ba9fe/pom.xml, therefore remove the okhttp from the dependency list then sync and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with this error. And after many search, found that I forget add Internet Permission to manifest.

After adding this permission, my error, resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If retrofit dependencies are not added or any other google services not added you are able to face this kind of issue. Also always check the manifest file if you are added Internet permissions

In Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in App level gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0'
```