# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

Tags: firebase

I am testing the new Crash tool:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

After going through the steps, the app launches and it crashes saying:

```
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incorrect provider authority in manifest. Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle.
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incorrect provider authority in manifest. Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle.
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
05-18 17:28:18.870 28743 28743 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Do you have an applicationID in your build.gradle?

Comment: @IanBarber: Oh wow, while editing build.gradle I removed it. My bad.

Comment: only http://stackoverflow.com/a/38224316/4663544 worked for me

Comment: Try `Android studio` > `Build` > `Clean Project`

Comment: I Fixed it by Making my application class extend MultiDexApplication when multiDexEnabled is true in app's graddle defaultConfig.

Comment: This error shown up to me even though I am not using Firebase on my project

Answer (score 163, accepted):

**1.**

Add the *applicationId* to the application's build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.app"
        ...
    }
}
```

And than **Clean Project -> Build** or **Rebuild Project**

---

**2.** If your minSdkVersion <= 20 (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Use Multidex correctly.

application's build.gradle

```
android {
...               
    defaultConfig {
    ....
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    ...
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
```

---

**3.**

If you use a custom Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="com.example.my.app.MyApplication" >
    ...
```

Comment: I got the same error and it has been fixed by the solution. I don't know the why, but it works.

Comment: This saved the day for me. Got the error while I was trying to run a Cordova app to an android device.

Comment: I have the same problem and the applicationId on my build.gradle. What can I do in that case?

Comment: @ekonstantinidis How did you fix it for your cordova app?  Can it be added to a config somewhere that correctly adds it when build.gradle is generated? (During `cordova platform add android`) ?

Comment: @Zach I don't think so. I added it after I ran `cordova platform add android`.  I guess it will get fixed once cordova gets an updated? Ps. I'm not using Firebase at all.

Comment: I have to comment, that, in my case it doen't work, even more, I got the applicationId in the build.gradle before I implemented the FCM .. is there any other knwon solution?

Comment: @Barthy I tested it, but didnt worked. Even though, I solve the problem.  Was some kind of pc errror. I get BLue Screen on windows, it restored some files, etc, and worked again all the project :/   . With Windows.. my mind is going to explode some day.. XD

Comment: Strange that this didn't get set, never had this issue before. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Accurate answer, thanks, worked for me... but, missing an explanation, why? And how did you figured it out?

Comment: I had `force close` on application start on API 15 and this solution wiped it out.

Comment: This answer is no longer functional in 2020

Comment: What do do if I'm getting this error inside another library module, where I cannot add the applicationId?

Answer (score 94):

I was with the same problem in devices with SDK < 22, but for me the reason is the MultiDex, the `MultiDex.install` must be in the `attachBaseContext` method.

If you are using MultiDex, try this:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this); //initialize other plugins 

    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

....
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        ...
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    }
...
```

Comment: It works, but there's a special class to do that instead of overriding one function and it's called MultiDexApplication, see answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312103/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider/40603347#40603347

Comment: Yeah it worked for me also, I always writing MultiDex.install(this) inside onCreate() method thanks dude

Comment: in my case I just updated compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' to last available version

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried all the other answers and was following Google and Firebase guides but this is the correct one, you're awesome man!

Comment: Thanks , how can you found it? but my question is my code lines app is not upper than 65000 why i should use it multudex and why i work on sdk>22 and it does not work on sdk<22

Comment: If your minSdk is 21 or higher, you shouldn't have to do any of this as the docs say it's already enabled by default. And yet, this problem is coming for me with minSdk = 21, any solutions for this?

Answer (score 75):

The accepted answer didn't solve my problem.

If you are using Multidex, your Application should extends `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application`.

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication{
     ...
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
      android:name="your.package.name.MyApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      ...
      />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks alot :)

Comment: How do you know these things?? Who told you??? I just started having this issue after updating to Android Studio 3 and installing "debug" apps. The "Release" version worked well. Now, with your solution also works the "Debug" version. I am so happy people like you exist!!

Comment: That's perfect answer

Comment: In all of these answers, none actually explains what adding multidex actually does to solve the problem (a perplexingly random thing to do in the face of such an issue)

Answer (score 37):

If you get the same problem but already have the `applicationId` set in `build.gradle`, you can also try the following:

- in Android Studio: `Build` > `Clean Project`
- in other IDEs: Clean, Rebuild, whatever...
- delete the build directory and possibly other caches or intermediate build files

Comment: And if you still have issues, delete the build directory and try again. I was stuck until I did that :)

Comment: Only deleting `build` directory worked for me. Seems like it was messed up by my last pull from the repo.

Comment: Deleting the build directory was the only solution for me

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem in Pre Lollipop devices. To solve that I did as follows. Meantime I was using multiDex in the project. 
1. add this for build.gradle in module: app

```
multiDexEnabled = true

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

2. add this dependancy

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

3.Then in the MainApplication

```
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

private static MainApplication mainApplication;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mainApplication = this;
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}


public static synchronized MainApplication getInstance() {
    return mainApplication;
}
}
```

4.In the manifests file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

This works for me. Hope this Helps you too :)

Comment: You shouldn't do all three jobs (extend MultiDexApplication, implement attacheBaseContext and change the menifest file) in order to make enable multidex only one is enough :D. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: If your minSdk is 21 or higher, you shouldn't have to do any of this as the docs say it's already enabled by default. And yet, this problem is coming for me with minSdk = 21, any solutions for this?

Answer (score 15):

you should be sure

to add this line at your manifest

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Worked for me too along with  multiDexEnabled true

Answer (score 7):

Don't include the whole play services library but use the one that you need.Replace the line in your **build.gradle**:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

with the appropriate one from [Google Play Services APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup),like for example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your module-level build.gradle :

```
android {               
defaultConfig {
    ....
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    .........
}
```

If you override `Application` class then extend it from `MultiDexApplication` :

```
YourApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication
```

If you cant extend it from `MultiDexApplication` class then override `attachBaseContext()` method as following  :

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(context);
     Multidex.install(this);
  }
```

And dont run  anything before `MultiDex.install(this)` is executed.

If you dont override the `Application` class simply edit your manifest file as following  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    .......>
     <application
         ......
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
    ......
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should works:

**Step1:**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "service.ingreens.com.gpsautoon"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

---

**Step 2:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

---

**Step 3:** Take another class

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
}
```

---

**Step 4:** Add this line on manifest

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was solved by adding this line to the module build.gradle:

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: I got "Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.play-services' not found."

Comment: @kaleemsagard put this in yout project `build.gradle`
`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }`

Answer (score 1):

For react native app, the error was `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"`
It was only getting for devices with Android Version < ~4.4

Solved it by just replacing `Application` in `MainApplication.java` with `MultiDexApplication`

NOTE: `import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem happened after we migrated to AndroidX.
For some reason, app was calling MultiDex.install() with reflection:

```
    final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.support.multidex.MultiDex");
    final Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("install", Context.class);
    method.invoke(null, this);
```

I changed package from `android.support.multidex.MultiDex` to `androidx.multidex.MultiDex`. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable "multidex" then the issue will be resolved but this issue is all about Android studio cache. So before adding "multidex" clear cache hope the issue will be resolved.

Delete `.gradle`, `.idea` and `.build` file after that clean cache.

`Android studio` > `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually adding the package name on the `build.gradle`, you can do it this way:

first add this line at the beggining

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
```

Then add this on the defaultConfig

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        applicationId = doExtractStringFromManifest("package")
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And finally add the doExtractStringFromManifest method

```
def doExtractStringFromManifest(name) {
     def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
     def pattern = Pattern.compile(name + "=\"(\\S+)\"")
     def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
     matcher.find()
     return matcher.group(1)
}
```

As there are a lot of Cordova comments on the answer, if you are working with Cordova, you shouldn't really edit the `build.gradle` yourself, it has a comment at the beggining that say

> // GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!

So, if you are using a Cordova, the best thing you can do is to update to cordova-android 5.1.0 or greater where this changes are already present.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was because Firebase SDK in Gradle file was set to a wrong number version.

I removed the Firebase debs from Gradle and re-installed them again using `Firebase Assistant`

Answer (score 0):

Go to android studio setting (by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+S` in windows), search for `Instant Run` and uncheck `Enable Instant Run`.

By disabling `Instant Run` and running your application again, problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code in proguard file.

```html
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

and it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I forget to add (or deleted accidentally) firebase core in build gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:xx.x.x'
```

Comment: 3 months have passed and this is now deprecated: DO NOT ADD THIS! Source = https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android (Obligatory: Thanks Google)

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error just on devices with API lower that 21. In my case, I have had to work with a project where `multiDexEnabled` option in `build.gradle` was already set to `true`. I checked dex file from APK and referenced methods number was less than 64k, so project doesn't need to be a multidex one, therefore I set `multiDexEnabled` to `false`. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed by using project level crashlytics gradle version 2.1.1

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
```