# Getting Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions after updating to the new firebase

Tags: android, exception, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have updated my application to the new firebase using the [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) and now when i compile my project i get the following exception.

Here is my **logcat:**

```
11:57:54.533 27844-27844/com.example.dayshift_2.traveyy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dayshift_2.traveyy, PID: 27844
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4871)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4466)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4406)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My **Build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dayshift_2.traveyy"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Not sure where i am getting this exception from. any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Which version of android are you testing on? I'm facing the same issue on KitKat, but my app runs fine on Lollipop / Marshmallow. Also, please post code or it would be very hard to help you.

Comment: Hi, I have update google play services to 30 and google repository to 28. I have initialized Multidex.install(this) in my custom application file. I am still getting the same error on kitkat but it works fine on later versions.

Comment: Did you solve the problem for KitKat devices?

Comment: @guilherme.minglini yeah i did following BKC answer. i have tested it on devices with  jellybean to marshmellow and works fine.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. If you haven't already, update your 'Google Play Services' to Revision 30 from Android SDK Manager > Extras.

[image: Android SDK Manager > Extras > Google Play Services]

2. And then add the line `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your dependancies (or simply remove `multiDexEnabled true` if not required)
3. Add this attribute to the application tag in manifest: `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

   If you already have a custom application class defined in Android Manifest, extend it from `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application`

Hope it helped!

Comment: I alread have a custom App in my project that extends the ORM application class. How should manage the need of android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"? Can you describe why this error is happening?

Comment: @EdgarDaSilvaFernandes All that "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" Does is this one line. "MultiDex.install(this);"

Comment: Hi, I have update google play services to 30 and google repository to 28. I have initialized Multidex.install(this) in my custom application file. I am still getting the same error on kitkat but it works fine on later versions.

Comment: As well as following all the instruction above, I also updated to 24.0.0 of the SDK, not sure if that made a difference. But all works now.

Comment: I have 31 rev. of Play Services but not working on pre 18 API devices

Answer (score 46):

Using latest Google Play services but was not working. For me this procedure is working:

1. Updated my Application class:

   ```
   public class App extends Application {
     @Override
     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
    }
   }
   ```
2. Updated `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```
3. Included dependencies:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, I've just forgot to place attribute
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" inside <aplication> tag in my Mianifest

Comment: Shouldn't `App extends Application` actually be `App extends MultiDexApplication`?

Answer (score 22):

It is so simple to fix guys.If you are using player-services and firebase both in your project make sure that you don't import all the available services in the google.Just import the APIs what you actually need.
For example:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

Doing this way it can give you **noclassdeffounderror** .To fix this

remove play-services and sync your project. If you have dependency like using ads or maps in your app then define the specific API. like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
```

Note: Maximum don't try to use **multiDexEnabled true**. This should be your last step to fix something.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Almost all comments and responses usually suggest the multidex enabling, in my case specifying that I was only using maps the only needed step, as described in this answer.

Comment: Works perfect, simply changed from 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1' to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'

Answer (score 17):

I *downgraded* my google play-service dependency from

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

which solved this issue for me.

Please refer to [the following Stack Overflow link for further description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423795/5744335).

**Please Note:** On upgrading to the latest google play-service 
 `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'`  it solved this issue as well.

Or you could selectively import certain services that you require, instead of importing all google play services.

Comment: *Upgrading* from 8.4.0 to 9.2.0 fixed it for me (using com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm, and also just having upgraded play services to revision 32, but that change on its own did not fix it, so I don't know if it is relevant)

Answer (score 13):

Step1: Fix multidex

Application class:

```
public class StudyNApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
 }
```

Grade file

```
defaultConfig { 
...
multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Step2: Fix  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Add two lib:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
```

It worked fine.

Comment: please update method to attachBaseContext - it works for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget it.

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved by adding this and lowering the play-service dependancy to 8.4.0 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

```
    @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

and add the following to the manifest

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error when I incremented the targetSDKVersion from 22 to 23 I spent minimum a whole day to resolve the issue. Now finally i find the result that use different play service api in your build.gradle file 
Source:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

I added only relevant Api's and my app is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

***Configure your app for multidex*** to resolve this issue.

> For `minSdkVersion` **21 or above** set `multiDexEnabled` to ***true*** in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown below:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    //...
    minSdkVersion 21 
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
  //...
 }
```

> For `minSdkVersion` **API 20 or lower**

1. Modify the `module-level build.gradle` and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown below:

   `android {
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       minSdkVersion 15 
       targetSdkVersion 26
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   //...
   }
   dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   }`
2. If you do not override the ***`Application`*** class, edit your `manifest` file to set `android:name` in the application tag as follows

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.myapp">
       <application
           android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        //...
      </application>
    </manifest>`

   2.1.1. If you do override the ***`Application`*** class Extend `MultiDexApplication`

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { //... }
   ```

   2.1.2. Or if you do override the ***`Application`*** class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

   `public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
       @Override
       protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
           super.attachBaseContext(base);
           MultiDex.install(this);
       }
   }`

for more [mdex-gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Hope this will be help others who are facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution for this issue at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37540593/3319687), please give it a look and thank **@Gabriele Mariotti**, he wrote:

In your top-level build.gradle you have to add:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Then in your module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ... 

}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(**R.string.default_web_client_id**))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

In my same case i changed requestIdToken and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.5.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'    
}
```

apply plugin: `'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

Answer (score 0):

try to solve...

in Gradle file

> multiDexEnabled true
>
> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Manifest file

application tag add this line

> android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Answer (score 0):

Before doing all those hectic solutions, try to **Clean Project** or **Rebuild Project** from Android Studio.

```
java.lang. NoClassDefFoundError
```

Exceptions is thrown when you change any **Class** name in your project but it couldn't get the changes you made in **Runtime**.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade your dependency in `build.gradle` file:

from:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

This worked in my case, hope same for you.