# Install com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.4

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

Please, I need install the lib: com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.4, because of the same problem [Sank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1942593/sanket-berde), in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421203/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseoptions). I try to install in build.gradle, with the comand:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.4'
```

but I could not.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-1-32?rq=1

Comment: I followed this post , but I could not make my project work. I will try to reinstall the android studio . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to update your IDE and Tools (this includes Google Repositories) following this guide: [Update the IDE and Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html) and then follow this guide to setup your project: [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: I had to uninstall , so just worked. Once installed Androis Studio , everything ran normally. Thanks!