# Firebase Error, without using Firebase in my project

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I'm Working on a GoogleMap Application **I'm not using Firebase** but I am getting `Firebase Error`

I've tried with `multiDexEnabled true` and without it, and it doesn't work.

I've tried updating `Google Play Services`, but it doesn't work

It works fine in **Android 6.0 emulator**

It gives me error **on a 4.4.2 real device** and in the **4.1.1 emulator**

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
```

**build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.navigationdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'


}
```

**Here Is My SDK Image**

[image]

Comment: try to use "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0" gradle in your app.gradle

Comment: Replace
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
with the only the libraries that you need. For more information on selective services refer this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421203/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseoptions)

Comment: @AndoMasahashi Bro I Try This It's Not Workign

Comment: @sunilsunny Bro I Try This It's Not Workign

Comment: what all services do you need. ? Try cleaning the project after adding the required services.