# Added FireBase analytic 9.0.0, when I run in older android devices I get error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I recently added the latest google analytic 9.0.0 into my app. The app runs fine in newer android phones but when I tried to run it in older android devices, I ran across this error (and i don't use firebase auth in any part of my app):

```
 05-31 11:50:33.466 5326-5326/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions', referenced from method        com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.  
 05-31 11:50:33.476 5326-5326/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zzb', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzaJ
```

The following is my gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
     }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'  
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  



    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.3"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    }

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }


    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'

    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'me.alexrs:wave-drawable:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.5.1@aar'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Answer (score 0):

1. If you haven't already, update your 'Google Play Services' to Revision 30 from Android SDK Manager > Extras.
2. And then add the line compile `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1` to your dependancies (or simply remove `multiDexEnabled true` if not required
3. Add this attribute to the application tag in manifest: `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

Comment: I tried 1 & 2, but still didnot work.
For no. 3, since for Google Analytic we are supposed to add "android:name="AnalyticsApplication"", I was unable to add multidex attribute