# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I keep on getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` on other test device (4.4.2) that I'm using. But works fine on my test device (Android 5.1).

I tried the solutions that I've googled and nothing seems to work.

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database. Can somebody please help?

**Here is the error log:**

```
06-03 01:36:29.607 2655-2655/mobapps.mypersonal.biz.grouptracker E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init> 06-03 01:36:29.617 2655-2655/mobapps.mypersonal.biz.grouptracker E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zzb', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzaJ 06-03 01:36:29.621 2655-2655/mobapps.mypersonal.biz.grouptracker E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getToken 06-03 01:36:29.629 2655-2655/mobapps.mypersonal.biz.grouptracker E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zza', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza 06-03 01:36:29.639 2655-2655/mobapps.mypersonal.biz.grouptracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mobapps.mypersonal.biz.grouptracker, PID: 2655
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4593)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5363)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 14):

This is what solved the problem for me:

1. Add compile **'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'** to
   app/build.gradle.
2. Add **android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"** to the application tag in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

   If you are using a custom Application class, skip the
   AndroidManifest.xml and make your Application class extend *MultiDexApplication* instead of Application.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is reported with newer versions mostly arround Revision 28,29 and its resolved in newer Play services versions so if you having this issue then make sure you have updated version of Google Play service in your Android studio. as older versions have it. To update Play services version..

Follow these steps:

1. Go to  Android SDK Manager
2. Go to Extra here you will find as shown in image below, update it to latest version and try to run project.

[image]

Then if **you are using MultiDex** in your Application,then make sure you have correctly done it.

In you **App level Build.Gradle** file use this code `multiDexEnabled true`

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reversebits.tapanhp.saffer"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

**Apply MultiDex dependency** in `dependencies` inside Same file.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Then inside your **AndroidMenifest.xml** file make sure that **Application tag have name of MultiDexApplication**.

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true">
```

### Note

**if you have your own Application class** and you are using it in your menifest file then you can **initialize multidex in your Application class** as follows,

```
public class AppClass extends Application {

    //this will initialize multidex in your own Application class
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **TapanHP** above I got this working quickly for me:

Short Answer:

I had `multiDexEnabled= true` set in my `app/build.gradle` file and this ran fine on Android 5.x.x above but any test device with 4.x.x (kit kat) would throw a critical error "*Unfortunately, YourAppName has stopped.*"

Debugger showed:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions' ....
```

**Note:** I also have a custom class that extends `Application`.

**My Solution:**
Added the following code to my custom Application class

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
public class YourCustomApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

...
}
```

No more critical crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, with this I have solved:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37364044

You must replace `android:name=".app"` with `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`