# App crashes after integrating with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am building my first Android app that uses Google Maps API activity. It works fine on the emulator. But after adding Firebase, it crashes on the emulator:

```
Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped
```

After a lot of search, I've found that it's useful to check logcat, it shows the following exceptions:

```
09-15 03:30:39.836 3541-3541/com.example.googlemapsapi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4560)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've done the steps in these solutions

- [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop)
- [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598691/noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseoptions)

But the problem still exists.

**MapsActivity.java file:**

```
package com.example.googlemapsapi;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        /*LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    */
        LatLng busLocation = new LatLng(37.783879,-122.401254);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(busLocation, 12));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(busLocation)
                .title("Code the Road Bus")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus)));

    }
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.googlemapsapi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
/*
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
    */
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
   // compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance,
Samuel Farid

Comment: On your emulator, go to Settings/Apps and click on _Google Play services_. Is the version number 9.4.52?

Comment: Please add four spaces at the beginning of each line of the stacktrace so that it is easier to read.

Comment: @qbix yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Please update the play services or try it on a real device, it will work.
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop).

Answer (score 1):

update your play service lib
 your project  class path is-classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
 and
 dependencies is 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'

so update your play service lib

Comment: How can I update play service lib? If you to update google play services through android sdk manager, it's already updated.

Comment: updated build.gradle file:                                                            defaultConfig { 
...
multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

Answer (score 0):

For me, my android emulator and android device were both crashing because I imported the crashlytics dependency within `<project_dir>/<app_module>/build.gradle` like so: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'`. After commenting out this line, my app stopped crashing. I am not sure the reason as to why crashlytics was causing the app crash but I did test it with and without specifically this import line and it worked out for me.