# android app work on android 5.0 but android 4.2.1 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, runtime-error

hello i am developping an android application on android studio

My program works on android 5.0 - 6.0

but when i try on android 4.2 or 4.4 its give to me

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1067)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5065)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4644)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4586)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

how can i solve that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
remove 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'  

from My Build.gradle  then add google elements 1 by 1 


  //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'   remove this
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:9.0.2'
```

then my app works on 4.*.* ,5.*.* and 6.*.* android versions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like possible duplicate:

you can try following things:

- Update your Google play service to the latest.
- Add multiDex support to your application. Check link.

[Getting Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions after updating to the new firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop)

Comment: my play service ver 30  i also updated  and already add multidex but it gives same error .    my app works on 5.0 and 6.0  there is no any error

Comment: My play service ver is 31 but same error on pre 18 API devices