# ClassNotFoundException with FirebaseStorage

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I've been trying to use Firebase's storage libraries to attempt to upload a file using Google's sample code in Android Studio:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<your-bucket-name>");

UUID imageID = UUID.randomUUID();

StorageReference pendingImageRef = storageRef.child("products/images/"+imageID);

UploadTask uploadTask = pendingImageRef.putBytes(imageData);

....
```

Which gave me this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage;
at com.myprogram.CreateProductFragment$1.onClick(CreateProductFragment.java:304)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage" on path: ....
```

My thinking was that this was an issue with dexing, so I rejiggered it and multidexed the application. This did not eliminate the issue.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: @adolfosrs, I knew there'd be something! I use Android Studio, and I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: which Firebase version re u using?

Comment: @UğurB I use version 9.0.1

Comment: i use 9.0.0 and classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'. it works fine. it may be versioning issue.

Comment: This is a runtime error, not an IDE problem. Most likely your device simple doesn't have the required version of Google Play Services. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop