# FirebaseUI auth is crashing on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to get authentication working with the new [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md). I'm getting the following error in LogCat

```
07-01 22:33:17.170 715-789/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-01 22:33:17.234 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zzf>
07-01 22:33:17.235 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zzf>
07-01 22:33:17.242 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$3>
07-01 22:33:17.242 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$3>
07-01 22:33:17.243 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zzf>
07-01 22:33:17.243 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$4>
07-01 22:33:17.243 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$4>
07-01 22:33:17.244 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zzf>
07-01 22:33:17.244 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$1>
07-01 22:33:17.245 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$1>
07-01 22:33:17.245 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zzf>
07-01 22:33:17.246 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$2>
07-01 22:33:17.246 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.internal.zze$2>
07-01 22:33:17.247 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc$zza>
07-01 22:33:17.247 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc$zza>
07-01 22:33:17.248 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc$1>
07-01 22:33:17.248 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc$1>
07-01 22:33:17.251 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-01 22:33:17.259 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zztw()Ljava/util/Set; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy-2/base.apk)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$4.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$4.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzaof(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.initGoogleApiClient(CredentialsAPI.java:148)
                                                                                at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.<init>(CredentialsAPI.java:64)
                                                                                at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.ChooseAccountActivity.onCreate(ChooseAccountActivity.java:64)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-01 22:33:17.261 715-773/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
07-01 22:33:17.481 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy D/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: throwable java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zztw()Ljava/util/Set; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy-2/base.apk)
07-01 22:33:17.517 715-715/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy, PID: 715
                                                                         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zztw()Ljava/util/Set; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy-2/base.apk)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$4.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$4.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzaof(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.initGoogleApiClient(CredentialsAPI.java:148)
                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.<init>(CredentialsAPI.java:64)
                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.ChooseAccountActivity.onCreate(ChooseAccountActivity.java:64)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I'm kicking off an auth request in onCreate:

```
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // already signed in
        Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(
                // Get an instance of AuthUI based on the default app
                AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and accepting the result in onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // user is signed in
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // user is not signed in. Maybe just wait for the user to press
            // "sign in" again, or show a message
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I think I've got it set up correctly. I downloaded my google-services.json and placed in in my `app/` directory.
Here's my project `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gmail.rixx.justin.cashcaddy"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The crash is happening right when the app opens, and I assume it's just some little thing with one of my configurations.

Thanks

Comment: have you enabled sign in methods in your Firebase project on console?

Comment: Yes. I have a working web app that uses email and password successfully.

Comment: can u share your app.gradle ?

Comment: I think the crash log you pasted here is not the cause of your actually error please look in to crash log carefully and try finding real cause.. If you find something else in you Log. do share it here..!!

Comment: i had a similar problem when i upgraded from the old firebase. Take a look at it maybe it can solve your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez I didn't even have play services installed, so I installed the latest version, but it didn't end up working for me. I updated the LogCat output to include more stuff. Not sure if that's useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue. It seemingly happened from one build to another which was weird.

Since the error message complained about missing gms stuff, what fixed it for me was adding following to my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
```

I believe this should already be a dependency of the Firebase Auth library, so I'm guessing it is some sort of bug.

Comment: Awesome! This works for me! I got an error when I added that dependency to gradle about mixing google services versions, but it went away when I did a gradle build.

Answer (score 1):

Version `0.4.2` of Firebase UI for Android was just released, it contains the necessary underlying changes to fix this issue.