# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this below error while launching my app.Even, the gradle build/sync finished successfully without any error. This error is related to `FireBase`, but I am not using `firebase` in my app. I am using `GooglePlayServices` `location`, `places` and `nearby` services.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4840)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4435)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4375)
```

Below is my build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.poras.whereami"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
}
```

I have searched on web, but didn't get any help. Please help me out.

Comment: update your setting gradle

Comment: @nEwDeV Can you please tell me what to update in settings.gradle?

Comment: @PorasBhardwaj Update `google play services` to latest version from `SDK`.

Comment: @jaydroider 'google play services' are updated.

Comment: @PorasBhardwaj May be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: @PorasBhardwaj, don't use complete `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'` dependency in your project, just use specific dependencies like ads, location or gcm from `play-services`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

and then `sync`