# ClassNotFoundException while running program

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have no clue why it is giving the following error whenever i try to run my map application.
The logcat is as follows

```
07-21 12:03:55.427 21046-21046/com.dutt.rishabh.locator E/AndroidRuntime:    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dutt.rishabh.locator, PID: 21046
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip  file "/data/app/com.dutt.rishabh.locator-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= [/data/app-lib/com.dutt.rishabh.locator-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 at   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5064)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4635)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4575)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:151)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1414)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dutt.rishabh.locator-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dutt.rishabh.locator-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5049)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4635) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4575) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:151) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1414) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**The source code is**

```
package com.dutt.rishabh.locator;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

**The gradle build file**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dutt.rishabh.locator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is my application but it always gives the error mentioned above.Please help needed! 
The above problem was solved but now it gives the following error.

```
07-21 12:32:20.223 26903-26903/com.dutt.rishabh.locator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dutt.rishabh.locator, PID: 26903
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dutt.rishabh.locator/com.dutt.rishabh.locator.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
    at com.dutt.rishabh.locator.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:350)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:464)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2373)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948) 
    at com.dutt.rishabh.locator.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The XML file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dutt.rishabh.locator.MapsActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly help in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: your next error because **name == null**

Comment: What name?-@isnotmenow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't include the whole play services library but use the one that you need, I think that replacing the line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
```

should solve your problem

Comment: @Rishabh glad it worked :) Btw now it crashes because `name == null` , I don't know where in the code you're setting that but it's causing the crash

Comment: Can u explain please?

Comment: @Rishabh I don't know because I don't have the full code, you should setup some breakpoints and check where it's crashing

Answer (score 0):

As part of enabling Google APIs or Firebase services in your Android application you may have to add the `google-services` plugin to your **root build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // ...
}
```

Then at the bottom of your app/build.gradle add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Read more at [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)