# NoClassDefFoundError FirebaseOptions, android?

Tags: android, firebase, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting this exception when I run my app on the device.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4990)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4596)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4536)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not even using the Firebase API still it is somehow getting reference.

This is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.supe.supermax"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.1.0'
compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: what about `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'` and add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Comment: Refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38178935/5744335) for solution.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks mate it works

Comment: @WISHY Glad to hear . Move ahead .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)**

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

You should use ***downgrade*** version `9.0.0` instead of <s>`9.2.1`</s>

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

And Add **multidex**

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Hope this help .

Comment: 9.2.1 is also a stable version. Most likely the device simply doesn't have the Google Play Services version that matches 9.2.1.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Indeed indeed sir