# Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Tags: android

Android `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions` error I got while running on device but worked fine in emulator.

My device API 15.
My Emulator API 23.

Any Help?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38178935/5744335) solution. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: tnks It works fine!

Comment: Your welcome. Kindly upvote it, if you found it helpful.

Comment: I done it for you!