# Commons.io error but working?

Tags: android, apache-commons

im using this code to "backup" a realm database on first run:

```
 try {

                        FileUtils.copyFile(new File(realm.getPath()), new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/old_db.realm"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

and i receive this error and APP CRASH

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1150)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1091)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)
at com.leifacil.vademecum.Atividades.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:118)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1150) 
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1091) 
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038) 
at com.leifacil.vademecum.Atividades.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:118) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the worst thing? ITS WORKING, its correctly copyingthe file and save at the ExternalStorage.... why worst? dont know the reason to crash -_-

ps: i use commons.io and FileUtils in other files, maybe it will crash too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Missing this at the Application in Manifest

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

PS: without it works perfectly for Android 6.0(api 24)

the problem was in the Android 4.1.2 (API 16)

where i found the answer:

[Getting Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions after updating to the new firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop)