# Android app crash with Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I'm working on an Android app that works well on Marshmallow and Lollipop but crashes on KitKat.

This is my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.moover.moovenda.moover"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.4'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.0'
    compile files('libs/cloudinary-android-1.2.2.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is the error I get:

> 09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
>
> 09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.
>
> 09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority is 3. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G360F_4.4.4_A024
>
> 09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfocat: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover E/SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: str_security_ctx is null
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.moover.moovenda.moover [ userId:0 | appId:10117 ]
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfocat: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover E/SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: str_security_ctx is null
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10117
>      09-20 18:20:00.629 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
>      09-20 18:20:00.679 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
>      09-20 18:20:00.689 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: Cannot add TimaSignature Service, License check Failed
>      09-20 18:20:00.689 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
>      09-20 18:20:00.719 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:com.moover.moovenda.moover
>      09-20 18:20:00.749 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions;)
>      09-20 18:20:00.749 22550-22550/com.moover.moovenda.moover E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.

Comment: Hi, did you have a look at this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks VallOn i solved, I was simply missing this from my manifest inside Application tag

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```