# Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions' on devices below LOLLIPOP works fine on Lollipop and above

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

```
10-06 17:29:08.688 22080-22080/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>
10-06 17:29:08.693 22080-22080/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zzb', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzcm
10-06 17:29:08.693 22080-22080/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getToken
10-06 17:29:08.693 22080-22080/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zza', referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza
10-06 17:29:08.693 22080-22080/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: contactify.syscom.com.contactify, PID: 22080
                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5112)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4707)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4590)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show us, your *app.gradle* and your *project.gradle*? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions after updating to the new firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly Add multidex true and compile file in gradle:app

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Then in manifest >Applications > change `android:nameandroid:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope it Would definitely work..