# unfortunately project has stopped after adding admob ads

Tags: android, firebase, admob

here is my app build gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.personal.numbermania"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //Here stablished how many cores you want to use your android studi 4g = 4 cores
}


buildTypes {
    debug
            {
                debuggable true
            }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is my project build gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Here is my error when running  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFCxH.png)

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: AdView adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: have you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: where you initialize  MobileAds.??

Comment: I haven't added that line.Should i add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you compile your code, you have `.class` files for every class in
your program. These files include bytecode that Java uses to interpret and run your program.
The JVM tried to find a `.class` file however, it could not find it causing a runtime error, `NoClassDefError`.

**Adding the following code to `build.gradle` file fixes this issue:**

```
dexOptions {
   incremental true
   javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}
```

**Other things to try in order to debug/solve this issue**

**Method 1:**

- Update **Google Play Services** to *Revision 30* from `Android SDK Manager` > `Extras`.
- Add `com.android.support.multidex:1.0.1` to your dependencies or remove `multiDexEnabled true` if it is not required.
- Add attribute - `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to the application tag in `AndroidManifest`

*Note:* If your `AndroidManifest` already has a custom application class defined, extend `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application`.

**Method 2:**

Another way of updating `Application` class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**Method 3:**

If method 1 and method 2 are unsuccessful, try downgrading your Google Play Services dependency down to `8.4.0`

Comment: what is firebase options?

Comment: public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}

Comment: give me ur mail id .Let's discuss in mail

Comment: You put it with your `MainActivity`

Comment: is it inside on create method?

Comment: I still have the error.Give me ur mail id.Lets discuss in mail

Comment: No, it is its own method. I've modified my answer to help you a little more. Also, if my answer works for you, please consider choosing it as  the accepted answer. If it doesn't work, could you modify your question with more of the relevant files.

Comment: both the solutions give error even downgrading to 8.4.0 didn't work

Comment: I have tried new method that u have posted.Even that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what else the problem could be. If I learn something, I'll update my answer. Also, I don't share my mail with others on StackOverflow.

Comment: my mail id is sribhanu93@gmail.com.u can mail me to this mail id.I will make sure that it is confidential

Comment: Did you do something different than what I recommended?

Comment: dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //Here stablished how many cores you want to use your android studi 4g = 4 cores
    }

Comment: I've updated my answer with the correct solution for anyone in the future having this issue. Glad you were able to fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To initialize before call AdView

```
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    //replace your ID
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

More details refer [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)