# Add Google Map to my android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments

the project build and run successfully but when i launch the app it crashes says unfortunately your app stopped.

can anyone help me please??

What is the wrong with this code?
here is the MainActivity.java

```
package app.elbalshy.mohamed.myapplication_map;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        googleServicesAvilable();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Perfect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        initMap();
}

    private void initMap() {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public boolean googleServicesAvilable()
    {
        GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvilable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(isAvilable== ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        else if(api.isUserResolvableError(isAvilable))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ResolvableError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvilable,0);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cant't connect to Play Services.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBT6CZPIS5XY37b0r0D-6OQEPFb4ebWKtA"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my Logcat

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/app.elbalshy.mohamed.myapplication_map-4.apk
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5022)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4631)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4571)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/app.elbalshy.mohamed.myapplication_map-4.apk
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4631) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4571) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.elbalshy.mohamed.myapplication_map"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Thats not your logcat log, Post your logcat

Comment: @Vijai here is my logcat

Comment: @MohamedElbalshy [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html#running). Read that and post the complete logcat error message

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: @Kinjal i just changed compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'   to      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: Are you using firebase in your app? There is no dependency for firebase in gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrade google play-service dependency from

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
```