# Application doesn't work on API 19 or less

Tags: android, sdk

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: salis.optimal.com.optimal, PID: 3913
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/salis.optimal.com.optimal-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/salis.optimal.com.optimal-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5196)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4788)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/salis.optimal.com.optimal-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/salis.optimal.com.optimal-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5181)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4788) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When i am trying to run my application on devices that the v.4.4 or less ,
i got this message , I've tried very this possible to solve this issue but it doesn't work.

Comment: You might have exceeded the [64K Reference Limit](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#about). Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop).

Comment: I've seen this question and it doesn't work for me @MohanadMohie

Comment: This is weird. Most of the `ClassNotFoundException` errors are because of the limit. Try to create another simple project that could replicate the problem with minimal code. That way you will be able to trace the problem.