# Issue with Firebase initprovider

Tags: android, firebase

I got a strange error when one of my app user who has an older version of **Android(4.1)** got this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4050)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4004)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1193)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4283)
```

I'm not understanding why this error has happened. My Firebase initialization code is below:

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (d.appuserexists(email)==true){
            d.appusermsgid(email,refreshedToken);

        }
```

It refers to my AWS Database and if the user already exists in the system the Firebase token is refreshed.

Comment: Check out this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: @Johnny...That helped...I discovered that the user was on a version of Android 4.0.2 not supported by my app