# failure to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Good day, i want to use Firebase auth in my Android App. This is my project level gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
}
    dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

    allprojects {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

This is my apps level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ibm.examplefirebase1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The failure shown up as

while i had download the latest android repository version

I tried with latest support repository but it still wont work.

```
"Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1
```

With

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Follow this link: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because there is no such module like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1`

The modules available in `com.google.android.gms` are:

- com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1
- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1
- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1
- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1

I think what you need to include is this: `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
 // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
}
```

for more details [check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop/38224316#38224316)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @Rushi Ayyappa

Comment: Yup, now facing another issue.

Comment: what is that issue?

Comment: Bro, the message log said that the: 
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.

Comment: there is something wrong with your tools:constraint class