# Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug Error while using MapsActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

I just want to call my Default `MapsActivity` in Android Studio when user clicks Maps from `NavigationDrawer` in MainActivity.

For Maps,I am using template in Android studio.When i am trying to build the application,it shows

> Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Here i include my Error Screenshot,my `MapsActivity` Code.
In my Android Studio,I have already installed google play service in SDK manager and i also get google API key for Google Map and i include it in `google_maps_api.xml`.

Please help me

MapsActivty

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ajay.com.dhruvafest.MapsActivity" />
```

I think these code are enough..I referred this from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ajay.com.dhruvafest"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ajay.com.dhruvafest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="Home"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Policies" />
        <activity android:name=".Events" />
        <activity android:name=".EventList" />
        <activity android:name=".EventDet" />
        <activity android:name=".Sponsors" />
        <activity android:name=".Workshops" />
        <activity android:name=".Developers" />
        <activity android:name=".Schedule" />
        <activity android:name=".Contact" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Updated** Error Screenshot
[image]

Comment: please remove compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1' becuase you are using  'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)Please check below is my gradle file and this gradle file work fine for me.**

**2) for google map you are using**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1`'

3) please remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`

**step 4 update your gradle file using below code i have do changes in that.**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ajay.com.dhruvafest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
}
```

**follow step 5 and 6 if above gradle file is not working**

**step 5 check below gradle file which i have checked and its working fine   in Build.Gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ajay.com.dhruvafest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        //if 2g or 4g
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    // important to run code on kitkat

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'


    // Map
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'


    // Volley
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

    //CropImage
    compile project(':CropImage')


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Step 6 and in Build.Gradle(Project:Your project name) file**

**you need to add this line

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `multiDexEnabled true` in your `app.gradle` file

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'

Comment: Yes i also add in compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1' my dependencies @YogeshBorhade

Answer (score 0):

The following steps are needed to start multi dexing:

Add android-support-multidex.jar to your project. The jar can be found in your Android SDK folder /sdk/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs

or

Try adding the following to your gradle,

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
}
```

add in dependencies,

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Now let your apps application class extend MultiDexApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

Comment: I add multidex jar to my dependencies and is synced.. but my MyApplication is already extended with ApplicationTestCase<Application>

Comment: Can you try once without extending??

Comment: New Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Comment: Then bro its an error of your firebase integration now. Multidex problem has been resolved. Hope my answer for multidex is useful to you.

Comment: No bro Actually i am not use firebase Integration in my application

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: thank you @Deep Patel ..Am not use any firebase Integrations and i don't know how these Errors after your answers..you are creating me diffrent error

Comment: Make sure your sdk>playservices are updated, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 please check below code and add this code in your gradle.**

```
 dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

**step 2 in defaultConfig add**

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

**step 3 in dependencies compile**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

**step 4 Please refer below code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.jmtechnologies.askuscash"
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
// ADD BELOW LINE
            multiDexEnabled true

        }
// BELOW LINE FOR HEAP SIZE
        dexOptions {

            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    }
```

**if still error will occur please update your gradle file here i need to check gradle file**

Comment: I updated my Error Screenshot and i also updated my gradle file and manifest