# error with firebase when i tried to build on low device version like kitkat

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

my app work on many devices but when i tried to build or run on low device like kitkat -- and lower it's throw this error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

and here is my gradle..

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapplicationId"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }



    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   // androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
      //  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    //})

//    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.2.3'
//    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5'
//    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
//    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
//    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    //compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   // compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've applied play services plugin too early, put it in the end of gradle file:

```
android {
   ...
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: @android, uncomment `multidex` dependency and correctly setup your Mutlidex app. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37751701/1083957).

Comment: worked !  so the problem was in `multidext`  btw ... why worked on another advanced devices ? 
is advanced devices like lolipop and marshimello dosen't required multi dex ? 

and why that conflicted with firebase ?!

Comment: There are many differences how app is being packaged (dex constructed) for pre and post lollipop APIs.