# Android App is crashing because of multidex support not enabled?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-multidex

my app is crashing when I am trying to user firebase-auth sdk.

My grade file looks like follow:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    api project(path: ':domain')
    api project(path: ':data')
    api project(path: ':device')

    ext.daggerDependencies = {
        implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$config.dagger"
        implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$config.dagger"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$config.dagger"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$config.dagger"
    }

    ext.rxDependencies = {
        implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$config.rxKotlin"
        implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$config.rxAndroid"
        implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:$config.rxBinding"
        implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$config.evnetbus_sdk_version"
    }

    ext.networkDependencies = {
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$config.retrofit"
        implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$config.okHttp"
        implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$config.gson"
        implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
        implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$config.glide"
        kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$config.glide"
    }

    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$config.timber"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$config.lifecycleArchVersion"

    daggerDependencies()
    rxDependencies()
    networkDependencies()
```

Error that I am getting is as follow:

```
2019-03-15 01:03:48.758 11964-11964/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dating.chat, PID: 11964
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/auth/api/internal/zzaj;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:43)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzk.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:54)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zza.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:26)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:34)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:82)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:761)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:359)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2000)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1975)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6585)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6115)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6021)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1748)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaj
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:43) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzk.get(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:54) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zza.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:26) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:34) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:82) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:761) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:359) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2000) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1975) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6585) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6115) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6021) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1748) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:43) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzk.get(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:54) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zza.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:26) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:34) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:82) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:761) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:359) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2000) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1975) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6585) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6115) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6021) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1748) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-03-15 01:03:48.760 11964-11964/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 26 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:83)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:735)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:818)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1041)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5913)
                ... 8 more
2019-03-15 01:03:48.761 11964-11964/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dating.chat, PID: 11964
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/auth/api/internal/zzaj;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:43)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzk.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:54)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zza.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:26)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:34)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:82)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:761)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:359)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2000)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1975)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6585)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6115)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6021)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1748)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaj
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:43) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzk.get(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:54) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zza.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:26) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:34) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:82) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:761) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:359) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2000) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1975) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6585) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6115) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6021) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1748) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:43) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzk.get(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:54) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zza.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:26) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:34) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:82) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:761) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:359) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2000) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1975) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6585) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6115) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6021) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1748) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-03-15 01:03:48.762 11964-11964/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 26 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.dating.chat-lCGo_36sLB73n9EoGnEdQQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:83)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:735)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:818)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1041)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5913)
                ... 8 more
```

I have enabled multidex but even then I am getting getting mutlidex VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.

I am using DaggerApplication class and have added

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base)
    MultiDex.install(this)
}
```

Can you please help me out with this? Thanks in advance!!! 
Let me know if any other information is needed

It also give the following error:

```
2019-03-15 02:00:06.626 3823-3823/com.first.chat I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2019-03-15 02:00:06.626 3823-3823/com.first.chat I/MultiDex: Installing application
2019-03-15 02:00:06.626 3823-3823/com.first.chat I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
```

Comment: try to add google play service in your gradle file.

Comment: I have added google play services classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Comment: see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39404082/8809599