# Gradle "manifest requires a placeholder substitution" error but manifestPlaceholders supplies a value

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to perform substitution within the AndroidManifest.xml file from the build.gradle android extension but am getting this error:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:89:16 Error:
    Attribute uses-library#com.company.platform.${encoding}@name at AndroidManifest.xml:89:16 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <encoding> is provided.
/Users/Company/Desktop/Checkout/android/Project/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
```

This is a snippet of the manifest file:

```
...
     </receiver>
   <uses-library android:name="com.company.platform.${encoding}" />
</application>
...
```

And this is a snipped of the build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionName cityVersion
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "City_$versionName")
        manifestPlaceholders = [encoding: "some value"]
        manifestPlaceholders = [version: cityVersion]
    }
```

I've also tried adding the manifestPlaceholders in the buildTypes i.e.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        manifestPlaceholders = [encoding: deviceEncoding]
        manifestPlaceholders = [version: cityIDVersion]
   }
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [encoding: deviceEncoding]
        manifestPlaceholders = [version: cityIDVersion]
    }
```

}

But I still get the same error.

Why is there an error about it requiring a placeholder substitution when one is provided for in the manifestPlaceholders?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to just add to the array. You are replacing it. Do this:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [encoding: "some value", version: cityVersion]
```

By declaring manifestPlaceholders twice for the same flavor/build type, your are replacing the previous one. After the previous one got replaced, your build failed because the property no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @jesobremonte: sir which section we have  put above line?

Comment: Either in defaultConfig {..} or in the individual productFlavors { flavorName{ .. } } depending on your needs.

Comment: @jesobremonte: what value we have to put sir inside the encoding and version variable sir please tell me ?

Comment: It really depends on whatever values you need in your build, I can't answer that. The above is just an example, you need to apply what you need to set instead. See this documentation on how to use it: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

Comment: @jesobremonte ok sir i tried but not worked for me, tell me 1 thing sir its related to the cordova-plugin-goolemaps plugin issue or any another issue?

Answer (score 4):

this

```
 manifestPlaceholders = [encoding: "some value"]
 manifestPlaceholders = [version: cityVersion]
```

should be like this

```
 manifestPlaceholders = [encoding: "some value"]
 manifestPlaceholders += [version: cityVersion]
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you running into manifest merger / manifest injection issues due to `manifestPlaceholders` defined in your libraries manifest, the issue is coming from the fact that you need to define a value for the `manifestPlaceholders` in your libraries manifest. That value is not getting overridden when you inject your real value in the consuming application. To get around this, you should only define those `manifestPlaceholders` values for `debug` builds in your library.

Like so:

```
android.buildTypes.debug.manifestPlaceholders = [
    authScheme: 'clientAppReplaces', authHost: 'clientAppReplaces'
]
```

By doing this you will be able to build your library. While also letting the client application supply the correct values for the `manifestPlaceholders`. Allowing your library to do all that heavy lifting it should. This is possible because libraries build as release builds (unless defined otherwise).

Client app `build.gradle` example:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.manifestPlaceholders"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode project.ext.versionCode
    versionName project.ext.versionName

    manifestPlaceholders = [authScheme: 'customSchemeValue', authHost: 'hostValue']
}
```

Comment: man I am hoping this worked, `android` decided to go to its next error.

Comment: I tried it and I think it worked, not sure why you were downvoted either. I got a lot more issues to resolve though.

Answer (score 1):

I had left the ${} symbols around my value:

```
<meta-data android:name="net.example" android:value="${XXXX}" />
```

Comment: I added the value without wrapping it with ${ ... }

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `+=` operation is applied on `manifestPlaceholders` instead of `=`. This is intentional and required as newer versions of the `Flutter SDK` has made some changes underneath the hood to deal with multidex. Using `=` instead of `+=` can lead to errors like the following:

```
Attribute application@name at AndroidManifest.xml:5:9-42 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationName> is provided.
```

If you see this error then update your `build.gradle` to use `+=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses Google maps

Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

```
         To get one, follow the directions here:

            https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

         Once you have your API key (it starts with "AIza"), define a new property in your
         project's local.properties file (e.g. MAPS_API_KEY=Aiza...), and replace the
         "YOUR_API_KEY" string in this file with "${MAPS_API_KEY}".
    -->
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the applicationId placeholder to the application gradle. This happens with the integration of Firebase, after updating to Gradle 2.2.0-alpha1

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.app"
        ...
    }
}
```

See: [Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312103/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider)

Comment: Ah, indeed, sorry... I have stared myself blind at this problem. I did not have it, which solved the error message, but I am still not getting any APK out of Android Studio... only, now also no errors/warnings