# Errors in manifest

Tags: android

After I switched from Eclipse to Android Studio, i got these errors, and i have now idea how to solve them, i'm still not familiar with AS.

```
[com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.8.0] K:\drawing-board\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.firebase\firebase-iid\9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:24:17-71 Error:
    Attribute permission#${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE@name at [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:17-71 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationId> is provided.
[com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.8.0] K:\drawing-board\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.firebase\firebase-iid\9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:26:22-76 Error:
    Attribute uses-permission#${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE@name at [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:26:22-76 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationId> is provided.
[com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.8.0] K:\drawing-board\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.firebase\firebase-iid\9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:34:27-58 Error:
    Attribute category#${applicationId}@name at [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:34:27-58 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationId> is provided.


See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


[com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.8.0] K:\drawing-board\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.firebase\firebase-common\9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:6:19-78 Error:
    Attribute provider#com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider@authorities at [com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:6:19-78 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationId> is provided.


See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


K:\drawing-board\AndroidManifest.xml:57:13-59:29 Error:
    Missing one of the key attributes 'action#name,category#name' on element intent-filter at AndroidManifest.xml:57:13-59:29
K:\drawing-board\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting


See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Thank you!

Sorry here's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.dessin"
    android:versionCode="25"
    android:versionName="2.1.4" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"  />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>    

            <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>



        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".StickerDialog" android:label="Dialog Example"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />


        <activity 
            android:name=".Paint"       
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>

            </intent-filter>



        </activity>


            <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />




   </application>

</manifest>
```

How i can merge the manifest?? and fix these bugs? and how the hell i can stop these errors for god sake!!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: post your menifest file to clear view

Comment: Ok, i will, thank you

Comment: Are you using Firebase in your project? I haven't used it but based on the error I think there's some stuff missing from your manifest file which is required for firebase to work.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to integrate firebase with : tools->>Firebase

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the applicationId placeholder to the application gradle. This happens with the integration of Firebase, after updating to Gradle 2.2.0-alpha1

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.app"
        ...
    }
}
```

Worked for me..

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368124/gradle-manifest-requires-a-placeholder-substitution-error-but-manifestplacehol)