# Android build error "AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution"

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building a reactNative app for Android, and I'm getting this error:

> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided.

What is this error? how to solve it?
Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368124/gradle-manifest-requires-a-placeholder-substitution-error-but-manifestplacehol/37588805

Comment: Why the downvote? this wasn't a clear fix! please elaborate before downvoting

Answer (score 46, accepted):

in the

> > app build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.chuchas.comm"
    ...

    // place correct redirectScheme~
    manifestPlaceholders = [appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.redirectScheme.comm']

}
```

Comment: sir are u fixed above issue after put above in build.gradle file?

Comment: i'm new in this. how can i find appAuthRedirectScheme in application?

Comment: shouldn't the redirect scheme same as applicationId? , i am having the same issue. Once I add the line , app disappears from the launcher

Answer (score 11):

In the app `build.gradle`, navigate to the `defaultConfig` section and add the following line.

Source Code

```
   defaultConfig {
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders = [appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.redirectScheme.comm']
}
```

Comment: And funnily enough, the value you provide doesn't matter. I fixed my project with the following line. Go figure!!! manifestPlaceholders = ['appAuthRedirectScheme': 'YOURSCHEME']

Comment: in case you use kts version of the build then it would be: manifestPlaceholders += mapOf("appAuthRedirectScheme" to "YourScheme")

Answer (score 6):

**Try to add manifestPlaceholders**

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#add-redirect-scheme-manifest-placeholder

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      appAuthRedirectScheme: 'io.identityserver.demo'
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade placed my api key in Gradle Script directory `local.properties` file and received the same error when I used the key in Manifest `meta-data` tag.  The following solved it:
In `build.gradle` Project file add:

```
id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.0' apply false
```

In `build.gradle` Module file add:

```
id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use: `manifestPlaceholders.putIfAbsent("appAuthRedirectScheme", "com.example.myapplication")` in the build.gradle app file

Comment: In my case this is the answer that worked.