# FirebaseInitProvider crash when trying to run app

Tags: android, null, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I implemented the new FCM on the app following the steps on the FCM web.

Now, I'm trying to run the app, but when I try it, the app crash with this error:

```
05-30 12:28:45.788 3002-3002/es.in2.otr.app.im E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: es.in2.otr.app.im, PID: 3002
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6765)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6357)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6297)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzah.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1789)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1764)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6762)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6357) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6297) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

As I can see, thre method is trying to get some value, where is null.

I searched for solutions, and found this post in SO. --> [Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312103/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider)

As solution they said to add the applicationId to the gradle build project file, but I got it:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.in2.otr.app.im"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

        testApplicationId "es.in2.otr.app.im.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
```

And stills  crashing.

Is there some workaorund or solution to this problem?

Comment: Afeter 2 month I come back with the same problem. Now it happens when I signed the APK and I try to test it. Any solution known?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
After adding the aplicationId i noticed that there were 2 apps installed on my device. I think it somehow changed the package name of the app leading the device to understand that were two different apps.

So i uninstalled the two versions and then it worked.

ps: The command line is not launching the app normally. It says:
 "Launching application...LAUNCH SUCCESS" but the app is never launched, i have to open it manually

**EDIT:** Just found out that i was type a wrong application id, now it works properly

Comment: Will you please guide to me how to check that application Id is correct or not because I have the same issue ?

Comment: Check Multidex libraries

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your dependencies (or simply remove `multiDexEnabled true` if not required)

Add this attribute to the application tag in manifest:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

If you already have a custom application class defined in Android Manifest, extend it from MultiDexApplication instead of Application

This works for me!