# Firebase Android C++ app crash on start

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to use Firebase authentication.

On gradle, I've put this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
}
```

When the app start, simply crashes.

If doesn't put the compile firebase dependencie, the application starts.

How can view what is happen?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for trying out the Firebase C++ SDK.

This isn't an answer more a set of suggestions to help debug the issue you're running into.

- You mentioned your app is crashing, what's in the log output?  Does it describe the problem?
- Are you sure the Auth Java component is included?
- Could you try reproducing the issue with the Authentication C++ sample application https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/tree/master/auth/testapp ?

Potential issues:
* Missing google-services.json will lead to a failure to create the FirebaseApp object on application startup.
* Missing the Java dependencies for the C++ SDK on Android.  This will lead to an assert when creating firebase::App and the firebase::Auth objects.
* Not signing your application with the signing key setup in the Firebase Console will result in all Auth operations failing. - I know you're not even getting this far but you may run into this after you get the app running.

In summary, the setup instructions in the sample should help debug this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/blob/master/auth/testapp/readme.md

Answer (score 0):

Finally doesn't crash. I've put applicationId on gradle like explains here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317943/1034225