# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider In Api below 21

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, firebase, google-api

I am getting issue in API 18 and it works in API 21 & Above.

Getting Error in Pre Lollipop version device and it successfully run  application in API 21 & Above :

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070150
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4882)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4485)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070150
                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:239)
                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:325)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzai.getString(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4879)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4485) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please need help..:-(

Thanks in advance.

I have tries below links ans search for that but didn't get result.
[Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312103/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider)

Waiting for someone for help :-(

Gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ascovalve.calculators"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/values-v21'] } }
    dexOptions {

        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental = true;
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"  
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1' 
   compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I have posted log error, do you need gradle file ?
let me know what you need to solve this issue :-(....

Comment: gradle and any line in which you accesing firebase methods

Comment: Check my edited question

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this cause of issue `configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common' }`

Comment: What error does your IDE shows?

Comment: Error show same as above

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas(

Comment: Its done. Don't know how but I have tried by Just putting style.xml in v11 & v14 same as I have put in v21.

Comment: @Bhumit how u resolve this issue... which entries is need in style.xml files.

Comment: @Garg's I just copy style.xml and paste it in v11 & v14 , Issue with different styles are used in different versions

Comment: @Bhumit thanks for your attention :). i have got another solution for it and that one working for me... If want then i can post my solution here for future assist to anyone.

Comment: @Garg's Yeah sure you can post your working solution that helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and resolved it by removing a leftover R.java file from a decompile of another Android app. (and yes, the decompile was ethical!)

That other Android app was using google-play-services as a library as well, so its R.java file was overriding the R.java from my own app's resources, making the runtime-used resource ID be invalid, thus causing an error when firebase attempted to use google-play-services.