# my own app is crashing after instaling from google play store

Tags: android, google-play

this app is very important to me, is there something that I'm missing?

[image: the image of the error in the google console]

I've recently add my own app to the google play store and I'm still new at this, my app was working fine before in android studio but after i published it, it only worked on a few number of devices and in the other devices its crashing and i made sure that the android version is 16. can any one help?

Comment: Hi Ali, welcome to stack overflow. Please read the how to ask a question before posting it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can log onto the play store developer console and view the crashes from your app to see what's up.

Comment: James i add a picture for the error that was given from the console can this be the error that's crashing most of the phones ? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Make sure ProGuard isn't deleting your classes. You can check if this is the case by manually building a release APK from Android Studio. If the problem occurs in the release build but not in the debug build, you probably have a ProGuard problem.

Comment: Have you had a look at this yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312103/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider

Comment: Andrew i didn't add any ProGuard to my application.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your app for multidex might help

multiDexEnabled true

Answer (score 0):

`extends MultiDexApplication` in your application class and enable multidex in gradle. I am getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

enable multidex support

```
defaultConfig { 
   multiDexEnabled true
   }
```

add this dependency to your gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

create an application class

```
public class Controller extends Application {

 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase)
 {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
        MultiDex.install(this);
  } 
}
```