# React Native Android Crash: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, react-native

I just recently launched my React Native Android app into production and a bunch of users are experiencing the following crash:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. I can't seem to reproduce it locally on any of my physical devices, and because it's Java and not JavaScript, I'm a bit unfamiliar. It looks like these users are all on Android 4.x, could that have something to do with it?

If you could help point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue that i was not able to reproduce but i get the following error in a simulator `Android 4.4`

I'm not sure if it's android vitals that just return a partial error or if it's actually not the same error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3446):    ... 12 more
```

This error was making the app crash on startup
I was able to fix it with this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317943/11170097

Use Multidex.

in your app/build.gradle

```
android {
...               
    defaultConfig {
    ....
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    ...
}
```

in your app/src/main/java/.../MainApplication.java

```
...
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends ... {
  ...

  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
      super.attachBaseContext(context);
      MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have currently encountered this issue at my project. The root cause of this issue is the unavailability of certain classes at specific API level.

For my case, I used `RoleManager` which is only available since API 29. Even I added a runtime checking like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
  // Use `RoleManager` ...
}
```

The above line of codes are run smoothly in Native Android project but React Native throws me the error. This is actually caused by the line of import !

```
import android.app.role.RoleManager
```

Although I cannot find any RN official documentation about this phenomenon at the moment, I believe RN checks if all imports are valid before running developer's codes! Therefore, it is a totally different idea with Native Android programming flow!

Solution could be moving everything you're using into a Util.java / Util.kt and complete you logic in another class!

Comment: what about API level 23?  it should be there https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService?hl=en 
How to do that in API level 23?

Comment: My case does not related which API level the code belongs to but is due to the import statement at the top of the java file. React Native has some weird implementation on recognising the import code. 

Try to use a new java file to implement all the codes and link to your bridging module. In this way, React Native can recognise the code. It is weird but works.