# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, apk, proguard, dexguard

my android application works fine on real devices. but when I install it on emulators like `genymotion` it installs fine. but when I run/tab it, it stops working and in the `logcat` this log is written

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=55172583; index=-1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=55172583; index=-1
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:2016)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(:58)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
        ... 10 more
```

no idea, why this is happening in the emulators. additionally I have tried to search on `google` if it was faced by others. the [closest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75047130/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider) was found on this site `Stackoverflow` but no luck as well as the user posted that the problem was `proguard` or `dexguard` but I have no idea how to solve this. could you please guide me on this? what is wrong here?

Comment: As per the link you shared for closest one, you need to use older version of firebase..try with that

Comment: @Meenal well I don't have access source code right now what can I do about this?

Comment: you need to change the version of firebase in gradle

Comment: @meenal, I don't have access the source code unfortunately now