# No Class defined error on release builds?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I seem to be running into an issue where only release builds crash with the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lretrofit2/Retrofit$Builder;` The class is irrelevant because it has not resolved other classes too in the release build. However, this does not appear on Debug builds which makes no sense at all. I have found that when I include these two dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.8.5'
```

the app crashes. However, when I exclude one of them, then the release builds work. Has anyone encountered this before?

The build config looks like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion 26.0.1

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionName project.rootProject.version.toString()
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig xxxx
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some code obfuscation tool like proguard or dexguard?

Comment: Nope - just normal multidex

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle

`targetSdkVersion 27`,

`compileSdkVersion 27`, and

`buildtoolsVersion to 27.0.1` or remove it (leave it as default. gradle will always look for the latest within this version 27)

The above solved my problem too. Although, i don't use `multiDexEnabled true` as i see no reason why when i have google play service library included.

Try removing `multiDexEnabled true` and re-build gradle.

Unless your are class extending Application class.Then you can use `multiDexEnable  true`

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

[check this question for possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045787/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-retrofit2-utils)

Comment: The solution was to update the support libraries too