# My app stops when I open it with 4.2 "api 16"?

Tags: android, back4app

When I open my app with samsung s3 its not opening.  It works with other versions.

This is the error:

[image]

My app works well with higher versions and my database is back4app.

My minsdk is 15.

Comment: You need to describe what your app is.  I would also include the stack trace error in the posting instead of just providing an image.  That will help others with the same problem find your question via search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your manifest

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{app id here}"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: it dose not work still the app working on lolipop or higher versions only and its install on the 4.2 version but its not opening

Answer (score 0):

the error now is :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParsePlugins
    at com.parse.Parse.isInitialized(Parse.java:273)
    at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:130)
    at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:126)
    at com.pluspath.App.onCreate(App.java:14)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1003)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4228)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This issue is different than the previous one. check for a similar solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34948154/5539802