# Force Android Studio to clean project whenever generating signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to make Android Studio preform a clean project automatically whenever I generate a signed APK?

Normally I do this manually before releasing an update, but apparently yesterday I did not and now my app strings are all out of sync. I'd like to prevent this from happening again by making Android Studio clean the project as part of the generate APK process.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify your Gradle script to clean while assotiating with progaurd for release

[Android Studio Build/Clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028009/android-studio-build-clean)

Comment: I think I understand your concept, adding a command to the "build.gradle(Project)" file,  but am unsure of the exact command

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on that, I haven't found any way to *modify the Gradle script*.